# Could anyone pass me some survey or books that display what is known about the surfaces of constant mean curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation, surfaces

Could anyone pass me some article (survey) or books that display what is known about the surfaces of constant mean curvature?

Preferably to articles or books with a lighter reading, otherwise you can send what you have. ;)

I have searched the internet, but I find little of what I want.

Comment: http://www.gang.umass.edu/gallery/cmc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMC surfaces is a very wide branch of study. I mean that they have been studied from many different perspectives (analytical/PDE's, integrable systems, etc.).

Also the choice for such a text would depend on the level of deepness that you're looking for.

That been said, I can recommend [this](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiU6MTnt-zZAhWlK8AKHSaNCqgQFggqMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww3.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de%2Fevs%2Fe%2F32.html%3Fevsver%3D867%26evsdir%3D819%26evsfile%3Dcmc.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2znxhMXkwz42e_QMkWEsPp) text. It is formed by the notes taken in classes given by Prof. Dr. K. Große-Brauckmann (TU Darmstadt) for 4th and 5th year students of mathematics. The prerequisites include only a short course in the differential geometry of surfaces. The approach here is mainly analytical. The most basic theorems regarding this topic are explained and proved.

If you are looking from some "starting point" in the topic, this might be your text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the question is a bit broad, but Rafael Lopez's book [*Constant Mean Curvature Surfaces with Boundary*](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642396250) comes to mind. It is fairly recent (2013) and if I recall correctly, the book also has a section in the end presenting some open problems.